# Upgrade Spartacus 4.3 to 6.0: Module not found

Tags: angularjs, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to upgrade Spartacus 4.3 to 6.0. I resolved most of the build issues. Got stuck with this error:

> ./src/app/spartacus/features/checkout/scb-checkout-base/components/scb-order-confirmation/scb-order-confirmation-items/scb-order-confirmation-items.module.ts:5:0-101 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./components/guards/order-confirmation.guard is not exported from package /Users/kirankumar/SCBGIT/js-storefront/spartacusstore/node_modules/@spartacus/order (see exports field in /Users/kirankumar/SCBGIT/js-storefront/spartacusstore/node_modules/@spartacus/order/package.json)